# Getting an additional HTML data using xhttp in Django

Tags: javascript, django

I'm working now with Django form based on ModelForm class which uses some JavaScript on my page to receive form data using POST.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    data_url = '/form-data/'
    dep_fields = '__all__'

    class Meta:
        model = Sign
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['name', ]

    class Media:
        js = ('js/form.js',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        attrs_dict = {'onchange': 'addForm(this)', 'style': 'display:', 'data-url': f'{self.data_url}'}
        if self.data:
           '''form fields logic'''
```

My Javascript does the following. It stores my form data like this:

```
var data = new FormData(obj.form);
```

and then sends in to my server every time I change any form field:

```
xhttp.send(data);
```

And form data looks like this and stored in form self.data:

```
self.data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['cpWuNU1JfK'], 'country': ['2'], 'region': [''], 'area': [''], 'color': [''], 'sign': ['']}
```

(I reduced the token for convenience)

So all I need is to get ID of chosen field from my HTML page (country ID in this case).
I added the following code to my JS:

```
var field_id = parseInt(obj.id );
xhttp.send(field_id);
```

And it seems to be working but I can’t understand where or how I can get this data (field_id) on my Django server.

UPD:
When I do like this:

```
var data = new FormData(obj.form);
var field_id = parseInt(obj.id ); 
data.append('field_id', field_id);
xhttp.send(data);
```

the `id` value is appends to my POST form.data like this:

`self.request.POST` : `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['rM0EwOPajAe4i'], 'country': ['1'], 'region': [''], 'area': [''], 'color': [''], 'sign': [''], 'field_id: [1]}`

What makes me thinks that JS sends it.
I just need to get `field_id` value separately

Comment: Have you tried `request.POST.get('country')`?

Comment: My POST looks like this now
`self.request.POST` :

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['rM0EwOPajAe4i'], 'country': ['1'], 'region': [''], 'area': [''], 'color': [''], 'sign': ['']}`

But I need to get "field_id" value which I am trying to transfer to the server

Comment: What do you mean by "field_id"? Are you trying to determine what field was sent to the server?

Comment: Yes! My form has fields and each field has it's own id:
<select name="country" id="1"
<select name="region" id="2"
etc.

Comment: You will have to explicity send the value of your field's `id` attribute with your JS. The `id` is only used in the browser. Or you could set the `id` to the same as the `name` attribute.

Comment: I updated question form above, because formatting there is inconvenient. Please take a look (below 'UPD')